# Two different icons for window title and task bar wpf

Tags: wpf

is there any way to set two different icons for window title bar and task bar of same 
And 
any ways to set icon size differ from 16*16
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Ico file can contain frames with different sizes (like 16x16 and 32x32). Window title bar and taskbar will choose icon with appropriate size (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.icon.aspx).

And also in WPF you can modify window chrome (window border and standard buttons) as much as you want, so you can show there any icon you want (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2008/09/08/custom-window-chrome-in-wpf.aspx)